# Attempting to compile any kernels, even vanilla ones, yields a certification error (continued from last thread)

Tags: debian, kernel, compiling, kali-linux, grsecurity

(Accidentally lost previous account after crashing my computer without saving keepass information. Continuing thread here).

I'm currently attempting to follow [this](https://micahflee.com/2016/01/debian-grsecurity/) guide  in order to install the 4.5.7 kernel with Grsecurity on my Kali Linux desktop. I am following that list of instructions *verbatim*, except for the fact that I'm trying to use Grsecurity's test patch for the 4.5.7 kernel and I'm running Kali Linux instead of straight Debian. Every time I attempt to compile the kernel, however, I get this error following the line "CC certs/system_keyring.o":

```
  CC      certs/system_keyring.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/certs/benh@debian.org.cert.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
Makefile:951: recipe for target 'certs' failed
make[1]: *** [certs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jc/Downloads/linux-4.5.7'
debian/ruleset/targets/common.mk:295: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/build/kernel' failed
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
```

I get this error, as I found out, for any kernel even if I apply no patches or modifications, so it has something to do with the tools I'm using to compile the kernel (apparently a system keychain of some sort). This is my first custom kernel, I'm not the most proficient at Linux, and I'm not sure what to make of the error. Can someone out there tell me how to fix my OS and compile my kernel? Bonus points if you can help someone really nooby understand what the problem was.

Thanks, John.

P.S., if it helps, here is the output of cat /proc/version:

```
Linux version 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Debian 5.4.0-4) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.6.2-2kali2 (2016-06-28)
```

UPDATE 1:
Suggested method  of adding --uc and --us to the make-kpkg command gave me the same error.